# Insert an ID into the loop trough my dbase

Tags: anylogic

I would like to use the loop trough my dbase and create_mydynamic event in MAIN for different process flows. I have to insert a function where it will only pick the pallets with the specified ID. So the different pallet types (ID) which I insert into my process with the source block should have the same ID like the pallets I will pick based on my database. So something like that:

```
agent.typeID= tor77_kunde1.id
```

Can you help me if it is possible?

```
List< Tuple > amounts =selectFrom( tor77_kunde1 ).list();
for( Tuple tup : amounts ) {
    Date today=date();
    Date future=tup.get(tor77_kunde1.picktime);
    long diff = future.getTime() - today.getTime();
    int n =tup.get(tor77_kunde1.n);
    process.create_MyDynamicEvent(diff, MILLISECOND, n);
    process1.create_MyDynamicEvent(diff, MILLISECOND, n);
}
```

[image: de]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you are freeing the last agent in the "wait" object. You need to free the one that has `typeID == n` in your DE.

So change your loop to something like:

```
for (MyAgentTypeWaitingInWait currentAgent : wait.getAgent()) {
    if (currentAgent.typeID == n) {
        wait.free(currentAgent);
        break;
    }
}
```

`MyCurrentAgentType` is the type of the agents waiting in "wait". (Uppercase!). Read on the "[enhanced for-loop](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fcode%2FFor.html&resultof=%22%66%6F%72%22%20%22%6C%6F%6F%70%22%20)" as well to understand better

Comment: Error the method getAgent() is undefined for the type Wait<Pallet> for (Pallet p : wait.getAgent()) {
    if (p.typeID == n) {
        wait.free(p);
        break;
    }
}

Comment: Should I also change something in createmyDE in Main? Or do you know where my mistake is?

Comment: check which methods "Wait" objects have that return all agents inside it. Might be named differently. Hence I said "something like this" and recommended (elsewhere) for you to start using code-complete :)